# Purging boiler with just one drain valve

Tags: hvac, boiler

I have read through how to purge a zone, but I still have a question. I don't have individual drain valves on each zone. So I am unsure what the process would be in order to purge a zone. And to clarify, I do attach my hose to the drain on the return side?

[image]

Comment: Um, what are you actually trying to do? Purging generally refers to removing air bubbles in the pipes by opening vents located at the high points...unless your system does not have a plumbed-in fill valve, a hose is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

yeah it would be better if each zone had a drain valve, but it's not necessary.  Close all but one valve, get the system running (circulating), and open that one drain valve - slightly.  With luck that'll force any air bubbles out.  Close that zone and open one other; repeat.

I dunno if that will be as effective as having properly placed valves on each zone, but it's about all you can do here.

Comment: So it sounds like purging may not work to get air out because of the limited drain valve? I had a boiler guy out here for 1.5hrs trying to get it out and nothing changed. He was draining from the drain valve on the outgoing pipes and not the return drain. Not sure if that would make a difference.